# Python : class programming and queuing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, queue

I facing a problem. I found a solution I'm explaining below but I want some advice aout to right way to resolve it.

*Here is the problem:*

I have a class object called *Item*. This *Item* has a method, call *make_request* which makes a *GET* request on a server, and save the result.
Now, I have implemented 3 *Item* object which calls *make_request*. The *Item* objects gonna call the method each 3 minutes, but these *make_requests* must be delayed by 1 minutes from the previous object's call.

Example :

- 14:00 - *Item0.make_request*
- 14:01 - *Item1.make_request*
- 14:02 - *Item2.make_request*
- 14:03 - *Item0.make_request*
- 14:04 - *Item1.make_request*
- 14:05 - *Item2.make_request*
- 14:06 - *Item0.make_request*
- 14:07 - *Item1.make_request*
- 14:08 - *Item2.make_request*
- 14:09 - *Item0.make_request*
- 14:10 - *Item1.make_request*
- 14:11 - *Item2.make_request*
- 14:12 - *Item0.make_request*
- 14:13 - *Item1.make_request*
- 14:14 - *Item2.make_request*
  ... etc

What I do actully is a **while loop** where I check the time minute and call the right object's method.

```py
from datetime import datetime

Item0 = Item(name="Item0")
Item1 = Item(name="Item1")
Item2 = Item(name="Item2")

while True:
   if str(datetime.now().time.minute[-1]) in ['0', '3', '6']: 
      Item0.make_request()
   if str(datetime.now().time.minute[-1]) in ['1', '4', '7']: 
      Item1.make_request()
   if str(datetime.now().time.minute[-1]) in ['2', '5', '8']: 
      Item2.make_request()
```

This is a solution, but it's not clean and I don't like it.
It is also missing 1 minute. I was thinking about using Queue.

I'm waiting for your advice :)

**EDIT : something more robust**

Thank a lot for your answers. I found a good solution for the first problem.

Now, I'm asking myself if I can, in the same context, use a Queue.
The idea is to call the *make_request* independently of the result of the previous *make_request*.

For example:
At 14:00:00 I call *Item0.make_request*.
Unfortunately, it takes more than 60 seconds to get the result of *Item0.make_request* but I want my *Item1.make_request* to be called independently at 14:01:00.

It happens sometimes

Answer (score 3):

Usually, when you have a number of items, on which the same thing is to be done, it is best to keep them in a list:

```
items = [Item(name="Item0"), Item(name="Item1"), Item(name="Item2")]
```

Then, no special logic is needed to see which the current minute is. Just run them sequentially with 1 minute delay:

```
while True:
    for item in items:
        item.make_request()
        time.sleep(60)  # 60 seconds
```

There is one drawback, about which you may or may not care: as it is, the time between two requests will be 60 seconds plus the time taken by `make_request()`. There are ways to avoid that, but perhaps you don't care about such details.

Comment: Well, it's a good solution indeed :) thank for answering me. Do you how to implement a queue using a list of items to manage the delay ? Just to know

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something overkill and configurable according to your need.

```
import time


# Assuming your class
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, number_of_ticks_to_act_in, *args, **kawrgs):
        self.name = name
        self.number_of_ticks_to_act_in = number_of_ticks_to_act_in

    def make_request(self):
        print(f"Making a requests from {self.name}")

# Item0 and Item1 will post every 2 mins and Item2 every 3 mins.
items = [Item("Item0", 2), Item("Item1", 2), Item("Item2", 3)]

# ?: Your configs
seconds_per_tick = 60 # Every tick can be in every 60 seconds or how you want it.
ticks_passed = 0 # This is a counter to keep track of ticks passed.
max_ticks_item = max(items, key=lambda i: i.number_of_ticks_to_act_in) # The counter gets set back to 0 once the max ticks that you stated have exceeded, this will let you run the code forever and never have to worry about the number surpassing int size. Overkill.
is_condition_met = True # You can set a condition to stop your forever while loop

while is_condition_met:
    # The counter is reset if it exceeds your max ticks.
    if ticks_passed >= max_ticks_item.number_of_ticks_to_act_in:
        ticks_passed = 0
    ticks_passed += 1
    time.sleep(seconds_per_tick)
    # Only Items with the same tick will get executed, this lets you have 2 or more Items of the same tick.
    for item in filter(lambda x: ticks_passed % x.number_of_ticks_to_act_in == 0,
                       items):
        item.make_request()
```

Hope this isn't too complicated. Added as much comments as I could.

Comment: Thank for your answer :) it's a good way to do it