# python : Multiprocess and requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests, multiprocessing

This post makes reference to [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65738427/python-class-programming-and-queuing/65739684#65739684) :

In the previous post, I was explaining that I have a **class object called Item**. This **Item class has a method, call make_request** which makes a GET request on a server.
Now, I have implemented **X Item objects which call make_request**.
The Item objects gonna call the method every X minutes, but these make_requests must be called independently.

Example with 3 Items:

- 14:00 - Item0.make_request
- 14:01 - Item1.make_request
- 14:02 - Item2.make_request
- 14:03 - Item0.make_request
- 14:04 - Item1.make_request
- 14:05 - Item2.make_request
- 14:06 - Item0.make_request
- 14:07 - Item1.make_request
- 14:08 - Item2.make_request
- 14:09 - Item0.make_request
- 14:10 - Item1.make_request
- 14:11 - Item2.make_request
- 14:12 - Item0.make_request
- 14:13 - Item1.make_request
- 14:14 - Item2.make_request ... etc

The principle is simple, the make_request method of the object Item_X must be called independently from the previous make_request method of the object Item_X-1.
Indeed, the make_request method must start at M minute (every minute), 30 seconds for example.
If it takes more than 30 seconds to get the result of the method, then it mustn't delay the next make_request (Multiprocess and queue?)

The answer to my previous post works but isn't enough robust :)

What do I need are possible solutions.
I wonder if you have an idea to do it in python3.
Can you provide me some advice (modules?) ?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to achieve this. There are a number of setups you can do to do this, depending on your exact use case. For example, splitting each item as its own job:

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger


class Item:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def make_request(self):
        print(f"{datetime.now()}: {self.name}")


items = [
    Item(name="Item0"),
    Item(name="Item1"),
    Item(name="Item2"),
]

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()  # blocks the main thread
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    scheduler.add_job(item.make_request,
                      IntervalTrigger(minutes=len(items)),  # every item is executed once per minute
                      next_run_time=datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=i),  # delay items execution by a minute
                      )
scheduler.start()
```

Sample output:

```
2021-01-19 23:27:27.926250: Item0
2021-01-19 23:28:27.928920: Item1
2021-01-19 23:29:27.924316: Item2
2021-01-19 23:30:27.927307: Item0
2021-01-19 23:31:27.927305: Item1
2021-01-19 23:32:27.931385: Item2
```

If the `make_request` takes more minutes to finish than there are items, it's possible to [re-trigger the job once it finishes](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html#missed-job-executions-and-coalescing) or else allowing [concurrent executions of the same job](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html#limiting-the-number-of-concurrently-executing-instances-of-a-job). Another possibility is to schedule jobs using [CRON triggers](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/triggers/cron.html) instead of using the `next_run_time` delay.

If you absolutely want items to be synchronised, then you can have a single job running every minute with `max_instances=len(items)`, & maintaining flags to see which item is currently running. However, this may be prone to race conditions & in general, more mechanical code is required.

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer. I'm gonna try and fit it with my code.